# Maven eclipse tomcat deployment slower than dynamic web project deployment

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, maven

Maven is a great addition to Eclipse but why does it take almost 10x as long to debug a Mavenized web service project compared to a similar one not managed with Maven?

For example, I have two Apache CXF projects. One is a Maven project and the other is just a plain Dynamic Web project.  Debugging the former via Debug As -> Maven Build using goals:  `clean package tomcat:run-war` or even just `clean tomcat:run-war`  takes about 160 seconds from when I initiate the debug action till when the webservice is ready for invocation.  However, debugging the latter via Debug As -> Debug On Server takes only 12 seconds.   This is killing any productivity I gained by managing my dependencies using Maven.

I see what Maven is doing each time, but it sure looks like some optimizations can be done to expedite the process, especially if this project has already been built before.

For someone trying, so far in vain, to sell Maven to my superiors, this is a serious impediment.  Any suggestions or ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Don't use the clean. Just use tomcat:run-war or run it from inside Eclipse via Plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: What do you think `clean` does? It cleans everything, forcing Maven to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for suggestion. I removed clean and all I have for goals is tomcat:run-war.  It takes about 70 secs, now thanks.  It this what I should expect?  Also, what do you mean by "run from inside Eclipse via Plugin in Eclipse?"

Comment: If you want to debug it using Eclipse, try Eclipse m2e plugin http://eclipse.org/m2e/ 

Don't forget to add WTP connector to be able to publish during runtime.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

You'll be able to install both of them from Eclipse plugin manager. Now you don't have to go through Debug As -> Maven, just deploy the project in an Eclipse server and debug it like you do with Dynamic Web Project.